# Data Access Layer in .net

Tags: .net, nhibernate, enterprise-library

I am looking for sample applications or some articles showing how to implement a data access layer using NHibernate or Entity Framework 4.0. The application contains a lot of logic with DB, but I don't want to move this logic into stored procedures or "smudge" this logic between layers (BLL and DAL). I am looking for nice examples how it could be implemented in real life application.

Comment: *Entity Framework*, or *Enterprise Library* (Entlib)? I suppose you meant the former?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both

[Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/) look at the repository

Nhibernate:

- https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture - an architecture using NH and looking to use EF later
- https://github.com/jongeorge1/Who-Can-Help-Me - I like this, its built on top of Sharp Arch
- big list of NH projects have a look some are systems http://nhforge.org/wikis/general/open-source-project-ecosystem.aspx

EF 4

- http://www.dofactory.com/Framework/Framework.aspx - have to pay for
- http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/ - Ntier app

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a big question, and there are lots of approaches, but this article gives a nice introduction to two patterns using NHibernate http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article119.aspx. There are also many articles available online that describe a more generic NHib repository approach.